# Heatmap legend plausiblity

Tags: algorithm, graphics

I need to display a heatmap (like the one below) with a legend displaying exact numbers for each color. But when thinking about the algorithm, it seems that it makes the legend completely meaningless due to data-point blending.

[image]

Algorithm used:

1) Normalize data points by their scores to 0-100 % of gray scale.

2) Draw circles of diameter D with gradient background & enlarging inner spot. Alpha of given circle is based on data-point score.

3) Re-map gray scale to given color gradient.

Problem: Alpha blending of two points with scores X and Y yields higher score than X or Y (see picture below with color check-lines). The highest heat color (red or the black) thus can be created just by blending multiple small data-points together.

Is an exact numbered legend for this type of heatmap really meaningless? Are there any alternatives? Or am I doing something wrong?

[image]

Comment: Do you have to use the algorithm you’ve described? Consider using this instead: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/10178/algorithm-for-generating-heat-maps Then your legend should be ok.

Comment: Good point, thanks! Laplacean interpolation looks very promising, hopefully it will produce graphically fancy results (which is also one of the criterions i need to meet).